# PHP/MySQL - Doesn't get the first ID in the table on button click

Tags: php, mysql

We are creating an HTML table where if a user selects a "Checkout" button next to a name, it will update a row in the database with the current date and time while removing them from the HTML table. It does this by grabbing ID of the row selected. For some reason, when there are more than one names in the HTML table, if you click the Checkout button of the first one, it grabs the ID of the name below it and updates that row in the database. If you click the Checkout button of the one below the first one, then it does executes the code as normal.

Page code:

```
    <?php
    // connect to database
    require_once('connection.php');
    session_start();

    //get session variable, if empty, unset and logout
    if(empty($_SESSION['department'])) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
    }

    $dept = $_SESSION[department];
    $eventsTable = $dept . "_events";
    $checkinTable = $dept . "_checkin";

    $query = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, "SELECT * FROM config WHERE deptCode='$dept'");
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $checkout = $row2['checkout'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, "SELECT * FROM {$checkinTable} WHERE deptCode='$dept'");
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $checkoutDateTime = $row3['checkoutDateTime'];

    if (!$checkout) {
    header("Location: checkin.php");
    }

    if(isset($_POST['checkoutUser']))
    {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($VisitorManagement, $_POST['id']);
    // set checkout date
    $query = "UPDATE {$checkinTable} SET checkoutDateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id = '$id'";
    if (mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, $query)) {
        header('Location: checkout-thankyou.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($VisitorManagement);
    }
    }


    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Visitor Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- nav -->
    <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="checkin.php">Check-In</a></li>
    <?php 
        if ($checkout) {
    ?>
    <li><a href="checkout.php" class="active">Checkout</a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="login.php">Admin Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center" style="margin-top: 5%;">
        <h1><img src="img/su-wordmark-vm.png" alt="Syracuse University"></h1>
        <?php
    $sql = "SELECT name from departments WHERE code='{$dept}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $name = $row["name"];
    echo "<h2> $name </h2>"
    ?>
      </div>


       <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns text-center" style="padding-top: 5%;">
      <p>Please select the checkout button of the visitor you wish to checkout.</p>

      <form id='checkout' method='post' name='checkout'>
       <?php
                 $checkinTable = $dept . "_checkin";

                $result = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, "SELECT * FROM {$checkinTable} WHERE DATE(checkinDateTime) = CURDATE() AND checkoutDateTime IS NULL ORDER BY checkinDateTime DESC");

                echo "<table class='checkin'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>SUID #</th>
                <th>Student Email</th>
                <th>Primary Affiliation</th>
                <th>Program</th>
                <th>Education Level</th>
                <th>Staff Member</th>
                <th>Reason for Visit</th>
                <th>Check In Date/Time</th>
                <th>Checkout</th>
                <th aria-hidden='true' class='hide'>Hidden User ID</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>";


                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $phpdate = strtotime($row['checkinDateTime']);
                        $dateTime = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $phpdate);
                                echo "<tbody>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['studentName'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['suid'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['studentEmail'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['studentAffiliation'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['studentProgram'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['studentEduLevel'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['staffMember'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['reasonForVisit'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $dateTime . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='submit' class='button' id='checkoutUser' name='checkoutUser' value='Checkout'></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='hidden' aria-hidden='true' name='id' value='" . $row['id'] . "'></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                }
             echo "</tbody>";   
             echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>";

                mysqli_close($VisitorManagement);
            ?>  
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: You only have 1 form and your code will add multiple inputs with name `submit` and `id`. This way when you read the posted id you'll only get the last value. You need to create multiple forms to work this way

Comment: Set the value of each submit button to the id, then look at $_POST[‘checkoutUser’] to figure out which one was clicked.  Get rid of the hidden inputs.

Comment: Please see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made a comment, but it's easier to just answer here.

You can only have one unique id attribute. The way this is outputting you'll have multiple forms with the same submit id. You could fix it by doing id="checkoutUser$row['id']" like this:

```
echo '<td><input type="submit" class="button" id="checkoutUser' . $row['id'] . '" name="checkoutUser" value="Checkout"></td>';
```

Comment: It may help to wrap your echo statement in single quotes as well. That way your html output won't have any issues where it needs double quotes. It's easier to write what you need, and to concatenate if needed between single quotes.

Comment: Although you are right about the fact that the id attribute must be unique to be valid html, your answer won't solve the problem here and also you have syntax errors in your answer...